# ios edit textfield infinite loop

Tags: ios, ios5, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

**Problem:** I have a method that handles `editingChanged` events and another method that updates my textfields from an object model.  The problem is that if I modify the text of the field that sent the event, it triggers editingChanged again and I enter an infinite loop (only in ios 5)!

**Example:**

```
- (IBAction)updateFields:(UITextField *)sender {
    if ([self myCustomValidation:sender]) {
        ... //update model
        //call another method that essentially does this
        field1.text = @"someformatted text"; //causes infinite loop if any field == sender
        field2.text = @"some more text";
    }
}
```

How do you work around this issue (without having to pass `sender` to all methods that send `setText:` messages) ?

Comment: are you using UITexfeild ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider implementing  the `UITextFieldDelegate`'s method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` instead of registering for the `editingChanged` control event.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    ... //update model
    //call another method that essentially does this
    field1.text = @"someformatted text";  //causes infinite loop any field == sender
    field2.text = @"some more text";
    return YES; // or NO, depending on you actions
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate) it should serve your purposes

> The text field calls this method whenever the user types a new
>   character in the text field or deletes an existing character.

Comment: i see, so the delegate method is not called when i programmatically update the text.

Comment: The delegate is called on user's actions, not on your programmatic changes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your own `IBAction`  methods, just implement UITexFeild delegates.

To detect **modifying text**, implement `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate.

To detect **end editing** , implement `textFieldDidEndEditing` delegate.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range      replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  //write ur code here
  return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

}
```